# Saving API response as a true .JSON file

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, api

**Background -**
I am writing some code that will take an API response, write it to a file, and also save it in a pandas DataFrame, and eventually perform some data QC.

**Issue -**
I have a `def response_writer():` function, which takes the response of an api call from another function (`def api_call():`) and saves it using `json.dumps`. I made some undocumented changes to my code and note that my code used to save the `api_response` as a .json file, however since making changes to my code, the 'api_response' is now saved in an 'extensionless' file, which although appears to be JSON, looks different when I open the file, to the pre-changes file...

**Files -** 
**Screenshot #1**. How my JSON data saved and looked, prior to the undocumented code change -

[image]

**Screenshot #2.** How my JSON code looks now, having made some undocumented changes -
[image]

**Current code -**
 These are my functions, following the undocumented changes -

a. Function that calls the api, and uses `json.load()` to save the response in a variable named `api_response`.

```
def api_call():
    url_list = url_constructor()
    for url in url_list:
        response = requests.get(url_list[0], auth = HTTPBasicAuth(key, secret), headers={"My-Firm":"543"})
    api_response = json.loads(response.text)
    return api_response
```

b. Function that is supposed to save the `api_response` as a .JSON file. However, whilst is appears JSON in the file, it doesn't have the same pretty structure as it did in before the undocumented change (see `data.json` in 2nd screenshot above).

```
def response_writer():
    api_response = api_call()
    timestr = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M")
    filename = 'api_response_'+timestr
    with open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as output_data:
        json.dump(api_response, output_data)
        print("--------------------------------------------\n", "API RESPONSE SAVED:", filename, "\n--------------------------------------------")
response_writer()
```

**Question -** Are there any benefits in the `api_response` being written to a file per Screenshot #1 vs Screenshot #2?
Ultimately, the objective is to make the `api_response` as easy to save to a pandas DataFrame as possible.

Comment: A "JSON file" is just a text file whose contents can be parsed as JSON. If you want it to have a `.json` extension, add it: `filename = f'api_response_{timestr}.json'`.

Comment: Is it because of file extension?

Comment: Your promblem is that you are using a system that assumes the filename is the last word on how to interpret a file: it's not even *trying* to treat it as JSON since it doesn't have the correct extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding the file extension might fix it:

```
def response_writer():
    api_response = api_call()
    timestr = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M")
    filename = 'api_response_'+timestr+'.json'
    with open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as output_data:
        json.dump(api_response, output_data)
        print("--------------------------------------------\n", "API RESPONSE SAVED:", filename, "\n--------------------------------------------")
response_writer()
```